# Enable text box when combobox item is selected

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to enable the text box when comboboxitem is selected . note the combobox item is not defined but rather i have used item source in combox to get the list of combo box items.i want to change the property of a text box when the combox item is selected .

(Comment pasted to original question)

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbInstrumentType,
              Path=SelectedIndex}" 
              Value="1" >
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" /> 
 </DataTrigger>
```

I want it in XAML only not in code behind. I dont want to repeat that for every index value –

Comment: That can be done;-) Show us what you have thusfar and we will set you on the right track. Make your bindings as much as possible dependent on the properties of the class you are binding to (the so called Viewmodel), avoid bindig a TextBox to a ComboBox. Let the state of your ViewModel change when the Combobox has a Property change and Bind your TextBox to *that*

Comment: <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbInstrumentType, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="1" ><Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" /> <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" /> </DataTrigger>, i want it in XAML only not in code behind. I dont want to repeat that for every index value. i have written this code inside style triggers of text box

Comment: I pass for now, no time. But others will hopefully take over.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do here. Do you want the textbox to be enabled when *any* combobox item is selected? Or when some particular item is selected?

Comment: ya i want textbox to be enabled when combobox selection is made. or it should be disabled always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the *better* way to do this is to use the MVVM pattern and bind to a property in your ViewModel (as Dabblenl suggested), I think you can achieve what you want like this:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Name="cmbInstrumentType"/>
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbInstrumentType, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

This will disable the textbox if no item is selected in the combobox.

**Edit:** Expanded code snippet

Comment: Yes i agree but the matter is when application runs . the textbox will be disabled at first . it will be enabled only when we do a selection in combo box otherwise it sholud remain disabled

Comment: Does the solution work?  I would also suggest simply using a <Trigger> here with the Property and SourceName properties set accordingly.  You don't need to use a Binding or DataTrigger to trigger off of UI-only elements.

Comment: Which propert for the trigger suits for combo box selection changed.

Comment: @user1379584: It is disabled at first. Did you try my example?

Comment: i dint get your example. where is it  i cannot see it

Comment: <TextBox.Style> <Style TargetType="TextBox"> <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" /> <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" /> <Style.Triggers> <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbInstrumentType, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}" > <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" /> <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" /> </DataTrigger>

Comment: @cunningdave: The problem with trigger is that the SourceName needs to be in the same scope as the trigger collection. It won't work when the combobox is a separate control. You'd usually use trigger within a template to control named parts of the template.

Comment: @user1379584: Why are you explicitly setting IsEnabled to false with a setter in your style? That is overriding the trigger. Look at my example code. I don't do that and it works fine. It'll be disabled at the start because SelectedItem will be null when the program first starts.

Comment: @MattBurland That's interesting... so a Binding targeted using a ElementName will ignore the current name scope and simply apply itself in a given context?  I'll have to try that out.

Answer (score 2):

i think the best way to do this kind of stuffs is using converters, so you don't have to pollute View with styles that handle that and the logic isn't in the view

something like this

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cboVersion, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToBoolConverter}}"
```

of course you need the ObjectToBool coverter, something like this (very simple without type checkings, etc... and should be improved)

```
public class ObjectToBoolConverter : IValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
     return value != null;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
     throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
```

}

and remember to register the converter in your resourcedictionary
e.g.

```
<Converters:ObjectToBoolConverter x:Key="ObjectToBoolConverter"/>
```