# Button Enablity WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` in which I have a `DataDrid` and in that `DataGrid` I have two `ComboBoxes`. Now what I want to do is when I select any item from both the `ComboBoxes` the Button which is outside the `DataGrid` should get enabled.

My `DataGrid` is bind to an `ItemSource` so does the Comboboxes.

I tries to use `MuliDatatriggers` but they failed as button is outside the `DataGrid` so those `ComboBoxes` will not be available to it.

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <ComboBox Name="Combo1" ItemsSource="{Binding Lst1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Code1" SelectedValue="{Binding CodeID1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">      
               <ComboBox Name="Combo2" ItemsSource="{Binding Lst2,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Code2" SelectedValue="{Binding CodeID2,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<Button Name="Add" IsEnabled="{Binding IsAddEnabled,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Farzi - if the answer was helpful for you - upvote it please. If it is the solution - accept it also

Comment: Cause as for today you have 6 question and 0 accepted answer!

Comment: No. The url u have provided doesnt answer my question. My button is outside the Datagrid so by using DataTriggers and Providing Element name for the Combobox will not help as they are inside the datagrid and button is outside the dataGrid.So it will not help.But if we can use Relative source property that might help..But I dont know how to use that in datatriggers as whenever i use it gave me an exception

Comment: Can you use MVVM in your application? This way you can implement the enale logic in your ViewModel

Comment: I am using MVVM as you can see the TAG i mentioned in my Question. And This is my UserControl I am talking about.So all Functionality is Done Behind-Code

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of answers to this question already posted.

For example: [Enable text box when combobox item is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514375/enable-text-box-when-combobox-item-is-selected)

The better way for you is to apply [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MikroDel with the MVVM that the **only** way to work right in wpf.. I do somthing like this but not with two cmbs and not on datagrid but that not need to be different at all because in each combo you set the selected index to your property on the viewModel and the same for button.

in this exemple i use `RelayCommand` you can read [hare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862570/how-can-i-use-the-relaycommand-in-wpf) about using it, but that not this q subject.

In addition I use a convertor 'cause like the button be enabled also if selected index = 0 so it implementd very simply

```
 namespace MCSearchMVVM
 {
     class MCBindButtonToComboBox : IValueConverter
     {

         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
         {
            if (value == null) 
               return false;
           return true;
          }

          public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
          {            throw new NotImplementedException();        }
      }
 }
```

Now to the real stuff ;)
Little advice before that is I like allways put the view(.xaml file) and the vm(.cs file) on the same folder, that why i find this example very fast lol

First we begon with the view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MCSearchMVVM.AddFilePage"    
         ...
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MCSearchMVVM"
         ...>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MCBindButtonToComboBox x:Key="enableCon"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       ...
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Background>
        ...
    </Grid.Background>

    <Button Content="Browse.." 
            ...
            Command="{Binding BrowseCommand}"          
            IsEnabled="{Binding FileKindIndexSelected,
                        Converter={StaticResource enableCon}}"
            .../>
    <ComboBox ... SelectedIndex="{Binding FileKindIndexSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" ... >
        ...
    </ComboBox>
   ...
</Grid>
```

Now the ViewModel :

```
public class AddFileViewModel : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
{
    ...

    private int _fileKindIndexSelected;
    public int FileKindIndexSelected
    {
        get { return _fileKindIndexSelected; }
        set { SetField(ref _fileKindIndexSelected, value, "FileKindIndexSelected");}
    }
    ...
 }
```

And the SetField func

```
 public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public virtual void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
        {
            string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

            if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                throw new Exception(msg);
            else
                Debug.Fail(msg);
        }
    }

     protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }

     #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged
 }
}
```

I Hope that direction was helpfull..
And sorry for my bad English =))